# Trying to create a macro to perform 100 iterations and paste resulting values (2 adjacent row cells) to a 2 x 100 array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that uses randomly generated numbers in calculations to produce results in two adjacent cells (let's say A1 and A2).  I am trying to perform 100 iterations where I'm simply "Calculating Formulas" on the worksheet and then trying to store the results of each iteration next to A1 and A2 (so iteration 1 would be in B1 and B2 and iteration 100 would be in CW1 and CW2).  Thanks in advance for your help.  Using Excel 2010 if that matters.

```
Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
Dim val As Variant
Iteration = 100

For i = 1 To Iteration
    Calculate
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial 
    Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you paste your current code into the question, we might be able to work out why it isn't working.  Without the code, we will all just be making wild guesses as to why your attempts aren't working.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would probably be helpful.  This is the first macro that I'm writing... I bought a book and also searched this forum and found a thread similar to my question, but when I tried to incorporate the code from that thread I got an error.  I'll add it to my original post now.

Comment: There are several issues with this code, but as it stands it will error because rather than `XLUP` you have `X1UP`. Easy to confuse is some fonts, which is why I've put them in upper case. Also if it isn't already, your `Paste:=xlPasteValues` needs to be on the same line as the bit immediately before.

Comment: @SteveLovell Good eyes!!  I had noticed the missing `_` (and assumed it was an error in pasting the code into the question) but had completely missed the `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your major problem was with the location you were selecting for the destination address - you were finding the last unused cell in column B, then shifting over one column (i.e. to column C) and pasting the first set of results.  Then you were using that same location for the second set of results, etc.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim val As Variant
    Iteration = 100

    'Use a "With" block so that it can be easily changed in the future
    'to refer to a specific sheet if needed
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To Iteration
            Calculate
            'Determine the last used column on row 1,
            ' offset 1 column to the right,
            ' resize to refer to 2 rows,
            ' set values to the values in A1:A2
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(2, 1).Value = .Range("A1:A2").Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

As pointed out by Steve Lovell, you also had a typo in your original code.  It is a good habit to include `Option Explicit` as the first line in every code module.  That will force you to declare all the variables that you use, and the compiler would have highlighted `x1Up` and given a "Variable not defined" error.

Comment: Should that code have worked by simply copying and pasting?  The line starting ".Range..." is being highlighted in yellow, and the code isn't working.

Comment: @crapon01 I noticed that I originally wrote `Range` when I meant to write `Cells`.  I updated the code about 14 minutes ago, but you probably copied it before I changed it.  Try copying it again (or just change the incorrect `.Range(1, .Columns.Count)` to `.Cells(1, .Columns.Count)`).

Comment: This box is telling me to avoid comments like "thanks", but Thank You!  Anything I can do to boost your score?  I clicked the up arrow, but apparently I'm too much of a newb.

Comment: @crapon01 You won't be able to upvote the answer as a new user, but you should be able to click the "tick" to the left of the answer.  (That will gain you some rep as well - I think you get 2 points for "accepting" a question.)

Comment: And a +1 from me too.